# How do I add external tables to Azure SQL DB through Visual Studio/SSDT

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure, sql-server-data-tools

My question is, how to you develop and deploy a database project to Azure SQL DB that uses external tables?

I’m using a Visual Studio 2017 database projects to manage Azure SQL databases.  I’ve been following the path of building the database in VS, then hitting the publish button, and it works great.

Now I am trying to add external tables for doing Elastic Queries.  In SSMS, I created the external data source and credential for it, and a remote table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [RemoteServer] 
    WITH (TYPE = RDBMS, LOCATION = N'myserver.database.windows.net',
     CREDENTIAL = [RemoteUser], DATABASE_NAME = N'MyRemoteDb')
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.MyTable (
     ID int not null,
    MyColumn varchar(10) not null
)  WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = [RemoteServer]
    );
GO
```

(Credential for RemoteUser also exists.)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

produces the expected result and all is fine in the world.

Now I want to add this to my database project so it can be deployed via publishing (in VS) for any future changes (and saved in source control).

I am getting the error:

```
SQL71501: External Data Source: [RemoteServer] has an unresolved reference to Database Scoped Credential [RemoteUser].
```

I can remove the error by setting the properties of all the external pieces to not build, but that defeats the purpose of being able to publish from Visual Studio.
I’ve tried removing the credential from the data source, so it doesn’t exist. It removed the error, but publish fails due to it missing the credential:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [RemoteServer] 
    WITH (TYPE = RDBMS, LOCATION = N'myserver.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = N'MyRemoteDb')
GO

 SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 46505, Level 16, State 15, Line 1 Missing required external DDL option 'CREDENTIAL'.)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try other way around 1) deploy everything on dev DB using script on SSMS 2) use schema compare to find all changes between DB and project 3) update the project based on schema compare. That way you should get all necessary components.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda unfortunately, that doesn't work. Comes back with the SQL 71501 unresolved reference error for the database scoped credential (that doesn't get pulled from the schema comparison, since it's a server object, not a database object.)

Comment: Hi @Rahn, have you find a solution for the issue? Thanks

Comment: @LorenzoBenassi, No, I'm still at a loss on this.  Per your other comment, I didn't want to go the other way around because of how I want to store the information in source control. (and I haven't been about to get the external tables to script one they've been created.)

Comment: I resolved this error by right-clicking on "Security > Add > New Item... > Credential"

Answer (score 0):

Elastic query in Azure is still in preview at the time of writing and Microsoft list a number of limitations in the overview page. Unfortunately one of them is regarding the  scripting of external tables and external data sources via SSDT. It is noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview#preview-limitations) (see second item in the list in regards to SSDT).